# wm_concat returning multiple of the same for select statment

Tags: sql, oracle

I have this select statement:

```sql
select m.title, m.category_code, c.company_name, wm_concat(d.director_name),    
wm_concat(a.actor_name) as actors
from
actors a
inner join actor_in_movies aim
on aim.actor_id = a.actor_id
inner join movies m
on m.movie_id = aim.movie_id
inner join movie_directors md
on md.movie_id = m.movie_id
inner join directors d
on d.director_id = md.director_id
inner join companies c
on c.company_id = d.company_id
group by m.title, m.category_code, c.company_name;
```

and it returns the same directors name one time for every actor....any way around this happening?

Tried this too:

```sql
select m.title, cat.description, c.company_name, wm_concat(d.director_name),      
wm_concat(a.actor_name) as actors
from
movie_categories cat
inner join movies m 
on m.category_code = cat.category_code
inner join movie_directors md
on md.movie_id = m.movie_id
inner join directors d
on d.director_id = md.director_id
inner join companies c
on c.company_id = d.company_id
inner join actor_in_movies aim
on aim.movie_id = m.movie_id
inner join actors a 
on a.actor_id = aim.actor_id
group by m.title, cat.description, c.company_name;
```

with the same results

EDIT:
Guess I just needed to think more, used distinct and got it!

```sql
select m.title, cat.description, c.company_name, wm_concat(distinct      
d.director_name),      
wm_concat(a.actor_name) as actors
from
movie_categories cat
inner join movies m 
on m.category_code = cat.category_code
inner join movie_directors md
on md.movie_id = m.movie_id
inner join directors d
on d.director_id = md.director_id
inner join companies c
on c.company_id = d.company_id
inner join actor_in_movies aim
on aim.movie_id = m.movie_id
inner join actors a 
on a.actor_id = aim.actor_id
group by m.title, cat.description, c.company_name;
```

Comment: Do you mean it returns duplicate directors for each actor and you'd rather it return the distinct name?  Can you use wm_concat(DISTINCT d.director_name)?  BTW -- be careful with wm_concat.

Comment: I actually added the distinct right as you were typing and it worked! Why be careful with wm_concat? Any other suggestions?

Comment: Glad you got it.  wm_concat is undocumented and unsupported by oracle, thus rendering production systems unsupported. listagg is documented and supported by oracle depending on your version.  Good luck.

Comment: @ssgtob1 - `wm_concat` was removed in Oracle 12c and later. I've ran into memory problems because of `wm_concat` in Oracle 11g - when used in large query with many rows it can use enormous amount memory and temp space.  Furthermore it is a very slow operation comparing to alternatives. If your final concatenated string is below 4000 bytes limit use `listagg` otherwise it is better to use `cast(collect())` with custom collection and function to convert it into `clob`.